# Cannot launch windows 10 mobile emulator

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, emulation

I try to launch app on Windows 10 Phone emulator and it doesn't starts.

I have no errors.

In Visual studio I have Ready 
[image]

And have this on Emulator
[image]

I waiting about 30 minutes, but nothing changes.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch Emulator using start Debugging
2. After that go to Build ==> and Cancel
3. The emulator continues to launch, it will take few minutes but it will come up
4. After that again do start Debugging, it gets deployed properly

This worked for me, hope this works for you too.